# How to freeze current viewport in JTree within JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, viewport, jtree

I have an instance of JScrollPane with JTree instance inside it. New nodes are periodically added to the tree in a way that new nodes are on top of the tree. When new node is added viewport moves down. How to stop it? I tried to use JTree.scrollRectToVisible, but the viewport visibly flickers in this case and I'd like to avoid it.

```
  node 1          - tree
---------------   - scroll pane
  node 2       | 
  node 3      ||| - scrollbar
  node 4       |
---------------
  node 5
```

in a few seconds "node 0" is added and here is what happens:

```
  node 0
---------------
  node 1       | 
  node 2      |||
  node 3       |
---------------
  node 4
  node 5
```

what I'd like to see instead right after "node 0" is added (and without flickering) is:

```
  node 0
  node 1
---------------
  node 2       | 
  node 3      |||
  node 4       |
---------------
  node 5
```

Comment: scrollRectToVisible should work without flickering - please show a SSCCE that demonstrates what you are doing exactly :-)